# Target "-resource-src" does not exist in the project "HelloWorldTest". It is used from target "compile"

Tags: android, build, robotium

```
<!-- override "compile" target in platform android_rules.xml to include tested app's external libraries -->
<target name="compile" depends="-resource-src, -aidl"
            description="Compiles project's .java files into .class files">
    <!-- If android rules are used for a test project, its classpath should include
         tested project's location -->
    <condition property="extensible.classpath"
                       value="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/bin/classes" else=".">
        <isset property="tested.project.absolute.dir" />
    </condition>
    <javac encoding="ascii" target="1.5" debug="true" extdirs=""
            destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
            bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
            verbose="${verbose}" classpath="${extensible.classpath}">
        <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
        <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/libs" includes="*.jar" />
            <fileset dir="${external.libs.absolute.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Why do I get a **BUILD FAILED**?

Target `"-resource-src"` does not exist in the project `"HelloWorldTest"`. It is used from target "compile".

My Android SDK Tools Rev20....

I don't  undersand, I feel lose hope

Answer (score 0):

it could be that your ${build.target} is set in the -set-debug-mode and -set-release-mode tasks. So, when calling the -compile task directly it is not calling either of those tasks as dependencies. so ${build.target} is never actually set.

try to override one of the tasks and have it set the ${build.target} when it is not set.

you can use the target attribute.

```
<javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
    source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
    debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
    .... 
>
```

i hope it works for you.