# Running Android JUnit tests with Ant (with external dependencies): Target "run-tests" does not exist in the project "XY"

Tags: android, ant, junit

I am trying to run Android tests with Ant. I stumbled on the same problems as described in [Can't build and run an android test project created using "ant create test-project" when tested project has jars in libs directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472059/cant-build-and-run-an-android-test-project-created-using-ant-create-test-proje). The solution provided there by emmby, works for me only partially, since I get an error message:

`Target "-resource-src" does not exist in the project "MyAppTest". It is used from target "compile".`.

To this issue, I found few further stackoverflow sites, for example: [Target "-resource-src" does not exist in the project "HelloWorldTest". It is used from target "compile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446212/target-resource-src-does-not-exist-in-the-project-helloworldtest-it-is-use?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

There, Kais suggests "*try to override one of the tasks and have it set the ${build.target} when it is not set.*".

1) How would one do what Kais suggests?

2) Is there any better/more up to date solution for running Android JUnit tests with external dependencies than emmby's solution?

I am glad to post more logs/traces/code/further information, when necessary.

I am using SDK version 11. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by starting all over: reverted the build.xml to default as it was generated. I also transferred all external jar libraries to /libs library and thereafter I can build the tests.